# How can i remove message information in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Code:

```
@bot.command()
async def perc(ctx,arg):
percList = []

for c in arg:
    arg3 = str(c)
    percList.append(arg3)

listtostr = ''.join([str(elem) for elem in percList])

perc = 0
perctext = await ctx.send(str(listtostr) + str(perc) + "%")

while perc < 100:
    perc += random.randint(1,3) 
    time.sleep(0.1)

    await perctext.edit(content = str(perctext) + str(perc) + "%")

    if perc == 100 or perc >= 100:
        break
```

Output:
<Message id=762965515735924777 channel= type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=483660674963079179 name='example
' discriminator='1234' bot=False nick=None guild=> flags=>16%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Message.content`

```py
@bot.command()
async def perc(ctx,arg):
    percList = []

    for c in arg:
        arg3 = str(c)
        percList.append(arg3)

    listtostr = ''.join([str(elem) for elem in percList])

    perc = 0
    perctext = await ctx.send(str(listtostr) + str(perc) + "%")

    while perc < 100:
        perc += random.randint(1,3) 
        time.sleep(0.1)
        await perctext.edit(content = perctext.content + str(perc) + "%")

        if perc == 100 or perc >= 100:
            break
```